# Having a dynamic View folder path during runtime in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade, laravel-views

I'm trying to build a saas application (saas here means software as a service) in `laravel 5.3`. I've build few service provider which collects the domain name, the theme being used and databases of those particular website. Now I'm trying to implement the pages with `view structure` through `service provider`. Now for example I'm having two different themes for two different domains. I'm having the set of HTML code in views in different folders, something like this:

```
View
----| Theme One
--------| Navbar
--------| Sliders
--------| Tabs
--------| Parallax
--------| Iconbox
--------| template.blade.php
----| Theme Two
--------| Navbar
--------| Sliders
--------| Tabs
--------| Parallax
--------| Iconbox
--------| template.blade.php
```

Now I want to define folder structure dynamically for these domains so that it should show the modules of their respective theme. Like suppose if I want to include sub-view of Navbar I just have to write

```
@include('Navbar')
```

and it should access the respective theme Navbar folder or sub-view. I thought of making a service provider and trying to set via config the path something like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->webView = $this->setPath();
    $this->app->singleton('webView', function()
    {
        return $this->webView;
    });
}

public function setPath()
{
    $themename = App::make('themename')
    if($themename)
    {
        $setpath = "..Path\Views\" . $themename;
        Config::set('view.paths', $setpath);
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Not found";
    }
}
```

But I guess when the application bootstraps it will ignore the configuration, I know there must be a better way in implementing this. Please guide me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create a **`ViewServiceProvider`** in **`App\Providers`** like this or copy **`Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider`** in **`app/Providers`** & change like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder;
use Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider as ConcreteViewServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ConcreteViewServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the view finder implementation.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function registerViewFinder()
    {
        $this->app->bind('view.finder', function ($app) {
            $paths = $app['config']['view.paths'];

            //change your paths here
            foreach ($paths as &$path)
            {
                $path .= time();//change with your requirement here I am adding time value with all path
            }

            return new FileViewFinder($app['files'], $paths);
        });
    }
}
```

then replace your **`Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,`** with **`App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider::class,`** in **`config/app.php`**. This will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now suppose I need to change it to the folder `themeone` which is being stored in variable `$themename` and its location is somepath\views\themeone I need to write `$path = "somepath\views\".$themename` inside the `foreach statement`

Comment: @NitishKumar yes the idea is close to same either you can set the path with your condition here.